# Way to declare a large variable depending on a condition

Tags: c++

Am reading through (the) C++ Core guidelines and encountered this rule: "Don’t declare a variable until you have a value to initialize it with" https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es22-dont-declare-a-variable-until-you-have-a-value-to-initialize-it-with

It describes the following code as bad:

```
SomeLargeType var;

if (cond)   // some non-trivial condition
    Set(&var);
else if (cond2 || !cond3) {
    var = Set2(3.14);
}
else {
    var = 0;
    for (auto& e : something)
        var += e;
}
```

Unfortunately this point fails to describe a way to how to solve this exact issue. Sometimes you just have to initialize a large object differently depending on a condition.
The only circumvent that comes to my mind is something like:

```
SomeLargeType * var;

if (cond)   // some non-trivial condition
    var = new SomeLargeType(123);
else if (cond2 || !cond3) {
    var = new SomeLargeType(3.14);
}
```

However even if I use a smartpointer, this feels somehow unnecessary/unsafe and most of all, worse than the initial way.

What is the optimal solution?

Comment: Maybe I'm just confused and/or dumb? But, as I see it, neither the suggestion in this question nor the given answer *correctly* addresses the last `else` case in the "bad code example."

Comment: There is a [link](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-lambda-init) in your article that answers your question...

Comment: Did somebody just undelete the comment by @StaceyGirl? If so, thanks - I'll paste it into my answer, for the sake of full self-containment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there is **no undefined behaviour** in the original sample code: all possible conditions are taken care of (by the final `else` block).  However, there is *potential* undefined behaviour in the answers so far given, as they replace the 'good' code in the aforementioned `else` block with, effectively, no initialisation and the return of a `nullptr`, which may later be the subject of an attempted dereference.

Also, there is no real need here to complicate matters by replacing the *instance* variable with a pointer (and this also changes the nature/logic of the code).

Using a lambda (as suggested in the [link provided by **StaceyGirl**](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-lambda-init)) is certainly a good way to go (probably the best, but that may be subjective). However, to keep the logic the same as the original code, one can apply the lambda to the object, rather than to a pointer, as so:

```cpp
SomeLargeType var = [&]() {
    if (cond) {   // some non-trivial condition
        SomeLargeType v1;
        Set(&v1);
        return v1;
    }
    else if (cond2 || !cond3) {
        SomeLargeType v2 = Set2(3.14);
        return v2;
        }
    else {
        SomeLargeType v3 = 0;
        for (auto& e : something) var += e;
        return v3;
    }
}();
```

Here, unlike in the original code (where a default constructor is first called, then one of three others), a constructor for `SomeLargeObject` will only be called **once**¹ and there will be no undefined behaviour. *It is this initial call to the (potentially very expensive) default constructor that, I presume, is the reason for this being cited as an example of "bad code."*

¹ If there are any doubts about how often the constructors are called, I can provide a complete MCVE (with some minor modifications to avoid the undefined `for (auto& e : something)` line), if such is requested.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a function. Also, don't use bare pointers with ownership (I assume that there's a guideline for this too). Example:

```
std::unique_ptr<SomeLargeType>
make_something(bool cond, bool cond23)
{
    if (cond)
        return std::make_unique<SomeLargeType>(123);
    else if (cond23)
        return std::make_unique<SomeLargeType>(3.14);
    else
        return nullptr;
}

// usage
std::unique_ptr<SomeLargeType> var = make_something(cond, cond2 || !cond3);
```

If there's no way for this function to be reusable, then a lambda might be appropriate, as shown by [Sopel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58693621/2079303)

Answer (score 2):

An immediately invoked lambda can be used as an alternative to a named function.

```
SomeLargeType* var = [&]() {
    if (cond)   // some non-trivial condition
        return new SomeLargeType(123);
    else if (cond2 || !cond3)
        return new SomeLargeType(3.14);
    else
        return nullptr;
}();
```

Note that some types may not provide a default constructor, in which case it's impossible to have a lazy initialization without using a boxing type.

This can also improve performance when the type is not trivially constructible.
https://godbolt.org/z/_V8t2T

Comment: @Sopel Now it returns `nullptr` and causes another UB when it gets dereferenced!

Comment: @StaceyGirl that's OPs problem

Comment: @Sopel Then what is the point of all this lambda noncense if we are just jumping from one UB to another?

Comment: @StaceyGirl I don't know what's your point. There is no UB anywhere.

Comment: @Sopel Following coding guidelines for the sake of following coding guidelines is a bad practice.

Comment: @StaceyGirl What are you even talking about. Before adding the `return nullptr` the code was producing UB when both conditions were false. I added it to make the behaviour equivalent to OPs.

Comment: @Sopel You don't need any silly lambdas for what you are doing. Just initialize with `nullptr` at the point of definition and then run conditional code.

Comment: @StaceyGirl we don't need a lot of things